# Hide the selected item from the custom spinner list

Tags: android, spinner, android-adapter

I have a Spinner displaying some items via an Adapter. The thing is everytime I click on the spinnerm it shows the list of all items that are selectable by the user. I would like to hide the item currently selected from the list.

### Example:

Here is my list of Items :

**Selected:** Item A

**Spinner List:**

- Item A
- Item B
- Item C

If I select Item B, it will become:

**Selected:** Item B

**Spinner List:**

- Item A
- Item B
- Item C

I would like to hide the selected item from the Spinner List. So, in the two previous cases:

**Selected:** Item A

**Spinner List:**

- Item B
- Item C

If I select Item B, it will become:

**Selected:** Item B

**Spinner List:**

- Item A
- Item C

Comment: Each item is typically a view in the layout, so if the current view is selected then you could just set visibilty to `View.GONE` and it will no longer take up layout space.  You would just have to notify your adapter about the change.  There might be an easier way in the adapter itself.

Comment: I tried to use View.GONE but it remove the selected Item of the spinner too, like this:

**Selected:** (Empty)

**Spinner List:**

 - Item A
 - Item C

Comment: Oh I misunderstood.  I'll let someone follow-up. I don't use spinners enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927994/remove-selected-spinner-item-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should create a list of seleted items. So everytime you select an item, you put on this list. After that you compare the two lists: the one with all values, with the one with the selected values and display only the items that aren't already selected.
I've already used something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> allItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    allItems.add("item a"); 
    allItems.add("item b"); 
    allItems.add("item c");

    selectedItems.add("item a");

    ArrayList<String> auxList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //populate an aux list without the selected items
    for(String itemFromAll: allItems){
        for(String selectedItem: selectedItems){
            if(!itemFromAll.equals(selectedItem)){
                auxList.add(itemFromAll);
            }
        }
    }

    //print the new list without the selected items
    for(String newItem: auxList){
        System.out.println(newItem);
    }
```

I hope it helps