# how to hide selected item from spinner list in android

Tags: android, spinner, hide

i want to hide selected item from the list of spinner just this questions [Hide the selected item from the custom spinner list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26307553/7784663) but i didn't get the answer. i just want to do exactly like the question in link my code is....

```
toolbar.xml

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
         >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

toolbarActivity

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c9c9c9"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/spintoolbar" />


    </LinearLayout>

spinnerAdapter

    public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     private Context context1;
     private ArrayList<String> data;
     public Resources res;
     LayoutInflater inflater;

     public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> objects) {
      super(context, R.layout.spinner_row, objects);

      context1 = context;
      data = objects;

      inflater = (LayoutInflater) context1
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     }

     @Override
     public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
     }

     // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
     public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);

      TextView tvCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);

      tvCategory.setText(data.get(position).toString());

      return row;
     }
    }



spinner_row.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>


spinnerAcivity



      public class SpinToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         private Toolbar toolbar;

         private Spinner spinner_nav;

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.spintoolbaractivity);
          toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
          spinner_nav = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_nav);

          if (toolbar != null) {
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

          }
          addItemsToSpinner();

         }

         // add items into spinner dynamically
         public void addItemsToSpinner() {

          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          list.add("Top News");
          list.add("Politics");
          list.add("Business");
          list.add("Sports");
          list.add("Movies");

          // Custom ArrayAdapter with spinner item layout to set popup background

          CustomSpinnerAdapter spinAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), list);
          spinner_nav.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

          spinner_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
             int position, long id) {
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected  : " + item,
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
          });

         }

         @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       final ArrayList<String> lastPressed = new ArrayList<>();
    final boolean[] isFirstTime = {true};
    lastPressed.add(0,String.valueOf(0)); // last pressed position
    lastPressed.add(1,"A");

     ...

       spinner_nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
         int position, long id) {
       ...
       spinAdapter.remove(list.get(position));
            if(!isFirstTime[0]){
                spinAdapter.insert(lastPressed.get(1), new Integer(lastPressed.get(0)));
            } else {
                isFirstTime[0] = false;
            }


            String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv)).getText().toString();
            lastPressed.set(0, String.valueOf(position));
            lastPressed.set(1, selected);


            spinAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       }
```

Comment: I hope it'll help you

Comment: is that item will be visible next time ? for example if i select A then list will display B and C, then  i Select B so it will display A and C in list? or it will display only C?

Comment: now it must be fine ... only change this line to what you need

Comment: String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv)).getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example for A B C

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");

    final ArrayList<String> lastPressed = new ArrayList<>();
    final boolean[] isFirstTime = {true};
    lastPressed.add(0,String.valueOf(0)); // last pressed position
    lastPressed.add(1,"A"); // removed object

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_view,list);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_id);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            arrayAdapter.remove(list.get(position));
            if(!isFirstTime[0]){
                arrayAdapter.insert(lastPressed.get(1), new Integer(lastPressed.get(0)));
            } else {
                isFirstTime[0] = false;
            }


            String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv)).getText().toString();
            lastPressed.set(0, String.valueOf(position));
            lastPressed.set(1, selected);


            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

}